# How to solve Mismatch "13" in vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Ok... so im triying to start using vba... I just started a week ago so i think this problem is very easy to solve but I just dont have idea what to do and all I try just doesnt work...

I have two textboxes... i need if i put a code of a product into the (codigoa textbox then the product will appear in the textbox (Produc) (without t) and if i put the producto the code will appear into the textbox of codigoa. So the part of of codigoa_afterupdate is workin good but with the product one im getting the error Mysmatch "13")

The code... (I triyed like 20 different codes)

---

```
Private Sub codigoa_AfterUpdate ()

On Error Resume Next

produc = Application.VLookup(CLng(codigoa, Sheets("inventario").Range("matrix"), 2, 0))

End Sub

Private Sub produc_afterupdate ()

codigoa = Application.VLookup(produc.Text, Sheets("inventario").Range("matrix"), 1, 0)

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your `CLng` is misplaced

Comment: Hi! Do i have to put it like Vlookup(Clng(Product.text)....?

Comment: You have to write ``produc = Application.VLookup(CLng(codigoa), Sheets("inventario").Range("matrix"), 2, 0)`` (note the place of parenthesis).

Comment: Yes, its in the first part of my code... you can see it in the question, But how can i put the product name into the textbox "produc" and get the code of that product in the textbox (codigoa)?

Comment: I think you are mixing data. Your first VlookUp is searching **a number** and second one is searching **a text**. Try converting the text into a numeric value and then do the VlookUp. Also, are you sure it's working good? try deleting `On Error Resume Next` because it just *hides* errors, but they still occur

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd `VLookup` can't work because it is looking for `produc.Text` in the *first* column of the "matrix" range, where you have product *codes*.

A workaround would be to define a matrix2 range, where you would have product names in the first column and product codes in the second. Personally, I would just "copy" product codes to the right of product names in your existing table using formulas, and define matrix2 to cover the 2nd and 3rd columns. Finally, you would use matrix2 in `Sub produc_AfterUpdate`:

```
codigoa = Application.VLookup(produc.Text, Sheets("inventario").Range("matrix2"), 2, 0)
```

I initially thought you would run into a race condition because updating the other textbox might trigger its AfterUpdate event, updating the first one and entering a loop, but a quick check confirmed this is not the case.

Comment: Yeah, i find it today at the morning, i Used to think that vlookup searched for all directions, but then i searched and i found it in internet, Thanks for the help and for the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark because you did not post any example dataa, but your first Vlookup works when searching **a number** and second one does not works when searching **a text*.

So I think you are mixing tyoes of data. `VLOOKUP` is sensitive to numeric and string values.

[image]

As you can see, all values in column A are being recognized as numbers.

My code is this:

```
Sub test()
Dim STR As String
Dim MyNum As Long

MyNum = 3
STR = 3

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Debug.Print .VLookup(MyNum, Range("A1:B5"), 2, 0)
    Debug.Print .VLookup(STR, Range("A1:B5"), 2, 0)
End With


End Sub
```

Line `Debug.Print .VLookup(STR, Range("A1:B5"), 2, 0)` rises an error, because `STR` is a string value, not a number. If I do:

```
Debug.Print .VLookup(CLng(STR), Range("A1:B5"), 2, 0)
```

then it works perfectly.

Now same data but numbers being recognized as text:

[image]

Now my code is:

```
Dim STR As String
Dim MyNum As Long

MyNum = 3
STR = 3

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Debug.Print .VLookup(STR, Range("A1:B5"), 2, 0)
    Debug.Print .VLookup(MyNum, Range("A1:B5"), 2, 0) 'this one fails
End With

End Sub
```

It fails when searching the number, but it works when searching the text. I could fix it doing:

`.VLookup(CStr(MyNum), Range("A1:B5"), 2, 0)`

So working with texts or numbers is easy, but you need to work always the same data type. Hope this can help

Comment: The problem was that vlookup Dont search for letf columns and i didnt know that. then i used a mix of Match and Index and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help. Really like to see how people can be be this kind, thank you! Very Helpfull.